# HttpClient Task was cancelled

Tags: asynchronous, task, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to use HttpClient to asynchronously log a message to a REST service using the code below:

```
public void LogMessage(string operationURI, string message, EventLogEntryType logEntryType)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
                client.SendAsync(GetRequest(operationURI), cancellationToken).ContinueWith(
                    cw =>
                    {
                        var response = cw.Result; //(I get an error on this line)
                        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            LogMessageLocal(message, logEntryType);
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
```

Note: The GetRequestMessage returns an HttpRequestMessage.

But I get an error stating 'A task was canceled.'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this can occur when the timeout is exceeded. You might check your [timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout.aspx), and log how long it was outstanding before the exception to see if it is being exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

The HttpClient is disposed before SendAsync finishes. This causes a `TaskCanceledException` to be thrown.

1. Add `async` keyword to `LogMessage`.
2. Add `await` keyword to `SendAsync` and set its result to `var response`.
3. Do whatever you want to do with the response after awaiting it.